# Laravel Eloquent Controller Match

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table which contains details of an order

- ID
- Order No
- Stock Code
- Quantity to Deliver

I'm outputting in my view an order and doing a foreach on the items.

This results in a page which allows us to despatch a quantity of our choice.

My question is how do I pass the quantity which may have changed from the order to the controller to update?

For example.

```
<form>
@foreach($order->items as $item)
{{ $item->stk_code }}<br>
<input name="{{ $item->id }}" value="{{ $item->ordered }}">
@endforeach

<button type="submit">Send Items</button>
</form>
```

My controller (just an idea)

```
public function processDespatch(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $order = Order::where('OH_ORDER_NUMBER',$id)->first();


        foreach($order->items as $item){

            if($item->id = "$request ? ID"){

                PERFORM UPDATE COMMAND IN TABLE

            }

        }
}
```

You'll see above I've used the phrase "$request ? ID" here I'm struggling how I can link the result?

Hopefully somebody can help

Comment: Have you read the docs on using Request? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests.  Other than that, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: yes, it's not clear. Do you want to pass a quantity to your function, or whatelse? Is so, you can also pass it as parameter `public function processDespatch(Request $request, $id,$quantity)`, or in the $request, and then access with `$request->input('quantity')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your blade file your `foreach` should be as:

```
@foreach($order->items as $item)
    {{ $item->stk_code }}<br>
    <input name="items[{{ $item->id }}]" value="{{ $item->ordered }}">
@endforeach
```

Then your controller function shoud be as:

```
public function processDespatch(Request $request, $id)
{
    $order = Order::where('OH_ORDER_NUMBER',$id)->first();

    $input_items = $request->items; // it will return an array

    foreach($order->items as $item) {
        if (array_key_exists($item->id, $input_items)) {
            $item->update( ['ordered' => $input_items[$item->id]] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir are a genius.